# $setPristine is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<form name="inputdata" ng-submit="saveStudentInfo(student)">
    <div layout="row">
        <md-input-container flex="50"> <label>First
            Name</label> <input required name="studentFName"
            ng-model="student.studentFName">
        <div ng-messages="inputdata.studentFName.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
        </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex="50"> <label>Middle
            Name</label> <input name="studentMName" ng-model="student.studentMName">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex="50"> <label>Last
            Name</label> <input required name="studentLName"
            ng-model="student.studentLName">
        <div ng-messages="inputdata.studentLName.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
        </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

That is the form components.

```
 $scope.inputdata.$setPristine();
```

If I write this code inside the controller, it shows

> $scope.inputdata.$setPristine is not a function.

Any suggestions ?? What should i do ?
**Angular version 1.6.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method sets the form's `$pristine` state to true, the `$dirty` state to `false`, removes the `ng-dirty` class and adds the `ng-pristine` class. Additionally, it sets the `$submitted` state to false.

So, it doesn't work for individual form element. Do it for `form` instead.

Comment: But i didn't write any ng-dirty tag.
i have written **$scope.formName.$setPristine();** inside the js page in order to clear the form data.
Please help me how to clear the data ?

Comment: `$scope.data ={};`  //to initialize the form with new empty object.
`$scope.formName.$setPristine(true);` //set the form to pristine state
`$scope.formName.$setUntouched(true);` //To make the form untouched.

`$scope.formdata = angular.copy($scope.data);` // make the form new with new instance of object.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use [`$setPristine`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) on an input.

It should be used on a `form`.

Comment: Then suggest me how clear the data inside a form.

I have written
**$scope.formName.$setPristine();**

Comment: If you want to **clear** the form, then you can use:       `angular.copy({}, $scope.formName);`